# How to do a 2d quadratic fit in C++?

Tags: c++, math

How would you perform a 2d quadratic fit in C++?  The equation to fit is of the form:

```
f(x, y) = a*x^2 + b*x*y + c*y^2 + d*x + e*y + f
```

where a, b, c, d, e and f are the fit parameters. Is it straightforward to write? Is there a library that is free to use for that?

Comment: What do you want exactly do? Compute the coordinates/draw a quadratic spline?

Comment: @ul90 I have a set of points (x_i, y_i, z_i), and I want to know the values of "a" to "f" that give f(x_i, y_i) the closest to z_i for all the points i. It is like a line regression, but in 2d, and with a second order polynomial.

Comment: Note that, once you plug in your `(x_i, y_i)` points, your equation is linear in the parameters you want to fit.  This means you can solve it with a (multi-)linear regression.  There are a number of google-able tutorials online for linear regression -- it is probably best to get a handle on the math before you try to implement it in C++.

Answer (score 1):

```
Use the matrix to get the values of a to f.

                [ x1^2  x1^2  x1^2  x1^2  x1^2  x1^2  ] = [ f(x1, y1) ]
                [ x1*y1 x2*y2 x3*y3 x4*y4 x5*y5 x6*y6 ] = [ f(x2, y2) ]
[a b c d e f] * [ y1^2  y2^2  y3^2  y4^2  y5^2  y6^2  ] = [ f(x3, y3) ]
                [ x1    x2    x3    x4    x5    x6    ] = [ f(x4, y4) ]
                [ y1    y2    y3    y4    y5    y6    ] = [ f(x5, y5) ]
                [ 1     1     1     1     1     1     ] = [ f(x6, y6) ]

[x] * [T] = [M]
=> [x] = [M] * inverse of [T]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have more than six points. It is a fit, not an interpolation. Also, I would like to know how to proceed in C++.

Comment: As mentioned in another comment, the problem is actually linear. I found a solver, `gsl_multifit_linear`, in the [Gnu Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/). The matrix you have to feed him with is similar to your [T] (with more terms), but the matrices equation that is inverted is different, to suit a least square fit.